# haproxy wait until dns resolve backend

Tags: haproxy

I have 2 docker containers in the **same network** - `web` and `proxy` running `haproxy` with backend

```
backend web
    server web web:80 check
```

Also `init-addr` is set to `last,libc,none`, so it does not fail if can't resolve `web` on start.

If I start `proxy` first, `haproxy` reports `could not resolve address 'web', disabling server`.

Then I start `web`. It become accessible by name from `proxy`, responding on ping and telnet.
But `haproxy` still treats `web` backend down.

I expect `haproxy` retry checking backend `web` on default interval (every 2 seconds as per documentation), and, as resilt - trying to resolve dns again on every check.

How can I configure `haproxy` to wait until dns will resolve backend server name and then automatically up that backend?

Comment: What version of HAProxy (`haproxy -v`)?

Comment: it's from Docker Store, latest, 1.7.5

Answer (score 3):

Your current config makes HAProxy able to resolve hostnames only at startup as mentioned [here](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3).
Since it can't resolve `web` on start, the server in question will be disabled.
In order to make HAProxy do DNS resolve after startup you need to add a [resolvers section](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#5.3.2).
Example:

```
resolvers mydns
   nameserver dns1 10.0.0.1:53
   nameserver dns2 10.0.0.2:53

backend web
   server web web:80 check init-addr last,libc,none resolvers mydns
```

Then whenever `web` becomes resolvable you will something like this in the logs:
`Server web/web ('web') is UP/READY (resolves again).`